# How to make flexible multiple widget in row?

Tags: flutter, dart

How to make flexible multiple widget in row? I have been try like this, but it does not work

Error message: `A RenderFlex overflowed by 33 pixels on the right`

```
Widget myWidget(){
   List<Widget> list = [];

      for (var i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        list.add(
          Flexible(
            child: Material(
              child: InkWell(
                onTap: (){},
                child: Container(
                  child: Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Radio(
                        materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
                        value: i,
                        groupValue: group,
                        onChanged: (int){

                        },
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )
        );
      }

      return Row( children: list );
}

myWidget()
```

thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

Just **remove your Flexible Widget as a parent** while adding elements in the list and at last **add the list as a child of horizontal scrollview** as follow,

```
    Widget myWidget() {
    List<Widget> list = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
      list.add(Material(
        child: InkWell(
          onTap: () {},
          child: Container(
            child: Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[
                Radio(
                  materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
                  value: i,
                  groupValue: "hello",
                  onChanged: (int) {},
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ));
    }

    return SingleChildScrollView(scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal, child: Row(children: list));
  }
```

> Flexible and Expanded can only be used as a direct parent of a row or column widgets only.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
 Widget myWidget(){
        List<Widget> list = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
          list.add(
              InkWell(
                onTap: (){},
                child: Container(
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Radio(
                        materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
                        value: i,
                        groupValue: group,
                        onChanged: (int){

                        },
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              )
          );
        }

        return SingleChildScrollView(scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal ,child: Row( children: list ));
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Please try this.**

May this work for you!

Widget myWidget(){
      List list = [];

```
  for (var i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    list.add(
        Flexible(
          child: Material(
            child: InkWell(
              onTap: (){},
              child: Container(
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/15,
                      child: Radio(
                        materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
                        value: i,
                       // groupValue: group,
                        onChanged: (int){

                        },
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        )
    );
  }

  return Row( children: list );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:** Adding horizontal scroll

```
Widget myWidget() {
  List<Widget> list = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < 35; i++) {
    list.add(
      Radio(
        materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
        value: i,
        groupValue: group,
        onChanged: (int) {},
      ),
    );
  }

  return SingleChildScrollView(
    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
    child: Row(children: list),
  );
}
```

**Solution 2:** Use `Wrap` instead of `Row`

```
Widget myWidget() {
  List<Widget> list = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < 35; i++) {
    list.add(
      Radio<int>(
        materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
        value: i,
        groupValue: group,
        onChanged: (int) {},
      ),
    );
  }

  return Wrap(children: list);
}
```